# Eigenvalue bounds for a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a symmetric $(p\times p)$, positive semi definite matrix $\Omega$. If somebody says: find the eigenvalue bounds of the matrix such that 
$$w_1I \le  \Omega \le  w_2I$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix, how can I find $w_1$ and $w_2$? I already know what $\Omega$ is.

Comment: The best constants $w_1$ and $w_2$ are the smallest and greatest eigenvalues of $\Omega$, respectively. This is why the inequality in your post was referred to as an eigenvalue bound. 

Finding the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix is a well-studied computational problem; with algorithm implemented in software, both commercial and open-source.

Comment: Thanks!!!!        1.[implementation] The inequality is part of an optimization problem. $\Omega$ is a parameter that is being optimized. Which means $\Omega$ will vary. And then the eigenvalues would also vary.In an optimization/linear programming/implementation standpoint is that a acceptable thing to have in your code?        2. The other option is to manually set $\w1 and $\w2. If I manually set it lets say to 3 and 4, can I say that I am actually restricting the eigenvalues to be in the range of 3 and 4? In other words if its a 2-d matrix I dictating the size of the ellipse it draws.